# api does not work once deployed

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have an API resource that is working as expected as you can see from the screen-shot below.

[image]

But when I deploy and access it through URL something like this...

https://vatultwgoc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/oksoft?url=http://google.com

I get an error:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

What is the correct way to deploy API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you invoke your API with the correct http method. I just try to invoke your API, and I am getting "null" which matches your test invoke result.

Comment: I changed the method from post to get and it is now working as expected. But how did you test invoking post method? When I tried using a simple html form, I got an error - {"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'url\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@1cc5f5ba; line: 1, column: 5]"}

Comment: I used "postman" google crome extension to test get / post methods.

Comment: I used "cUrl" to the API with POST method.